# restar dos fecha-time en la misma columna y filtrar resultado por los que sean > 20 segundos

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, datetime, orderby

En la siguiente consulta en SQL SERVER 2014 realizo la resta de dos campos DATETIME en la misma columna y como resultado me da la diferencia en segundos. pero ahora quiero realizar un filtro al resultado por aquellos que cumplan cierta condición en este caso que sean > 20 segundos.

```
select fechaHoraLecturaDato, DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(fechaHoraLecturaDato) 
over (order by fechaHoraLecturaDato), fechaHoraLecturaDato) as RESTA from  [dbo].[P30]
order by fechaHoraLecturaDato

fechaHoraLecturaDato    RESTA
2020-10-12T10:17:58.100000  20
2020-10-12T10:17:58.100000  0
2020-10-12T10:18:18.101000  20
2020-10-12T10:18:18.101000  0
2020-10-12T10:20:58.101000  160
2020-10-12T10:21:38.125000  40
2020-10-12T10:22:18.100000  40
2020-10-12T10:22:38.118000  20
2020-10-12T10:22:58.100000  20
```

Teniendo en cuenta que el resultado es un ALIAS = RESTA no puedo aplicarle un HAVING O UN WHERE

Answer (score 2):

Hola podrías usar un CTE para obtener los datos así como lo tienes y posterior a esos datos aplicas el filtro quedando algo de este modo
Informacion sobre CTE.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
;WITH PreData AS (
SELECT fechaHoraLecturaDato, DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(fechaHoraLecturaDato) 
over (order by fechaHoraLecturaDato), fechaHoraLecturaDato) as RESTA 
FROM  [dbo].[P30])
SELECT * FROM PreData
WHERE RESTA>20
order by fechaHoraLecturaDato
```

Answer (score 1):

La condición la debes aplicar en el `WHERE` en la misma fórmula que utilizas en el `SELECT`.

```
select fechaHoraLecturaDato, DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(fechaHoraLecturaDato) 
over (order by fechaHoraLecturaDato), fechaHoraLecturaDato) as RESTA 
from [dbo].[P30]
where DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(fechaHoraLecturaDato) 
over (order by fechaHoraLecturaDato), fechaHoraLecturaDato) > 20
order by fechaHoraLecturaDato
```

Comment: Genere el siguiente error  Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.